# Ошибка с соединением с базой данных. Сервер не видит jdbc драйвер

Tags: java, сервер, eclipse, jdbc, клиент-сервер

Прошу строго не судить, я еще совсем новичок в Java. Возможно, мой вопрос из разряда "ноэтожеверисимпл". Есть графический интерфейс, клиент, сервер и БД на MySQL. Клиент забирает с TextArea графического интерфейса строку, отправляет её на сервер, вставив префикс в виде *. Сервер видя * в начале принятой строки должен соединиться с БД и отобразить таблицу в TextArea графического интерфейса. Реализовал все вот так + написал класс DBEngine, который проводит все действия с БД.

```
 public class DBEngine {

public static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbtest";
public static final String user = "root";
public static final String password = "root";


public static Connection con;
public static Statement stmt;
public static ResultSet rs;


public static void main(String args[]) {
    String query = "select id, name, age, email from users";

    try {
        // opening database connection to MySQL server
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        // getting Statement object to execute query
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        // executing SELECT query
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select id, name, age, email from users");

        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            int age = rs.getInt("age");
            String email = rs.getString("email"); 
            String all = ("Пользователь " + name + " , которому " + age + "год(а)/лет, имеет ID " + id + " и email  " + email);
            System.out.println(all);
            GUI.area.append(all);
        }

    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        sqlEx.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //close connection ,stmt and resultset here
        try { con.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
        try { stmt.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
        try { rs.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
    }
}

}
```

Причем при отдельном запуске DBEngine, все корректно отображается в консоли.
Вот сервер:

```
public class Server {

 public static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbtest";
    public static final String user = "root";
    public static final String password = "root";

    // JDBC variables for opening and managing connection
    public static Connection con;
    public static Statement stmt;
    public static ResultSet rs;
private static ServerSocket server;
private static int port = 9876;


public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    server = new ServerSocket(port);
    DBEngine show1DB = new DBEngine();
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Ожидаем клиента");
        Socket socket = server.accept();
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        String message = (String) ois.readObject();
        int dlina = message.length();
        System.out.println("Получено сообщение: " + message);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        oos.writeObject(dlina+" ");
        ois.close();
        oos.close();
        socket.close();
        if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) break;
        if(message.startsWith("*"))
            show1DB.main(args);



    }
    System.out.println("Сервер отключен");
    server.close();
}
 }
```

А вот, собственно, и сама ошибка на сервере
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо Вам, если прочли до сюда)

Comment: Наверное не находит jdbc драйвер. Есть такая штука в java, classpath называется. И эта java находит только те классы, которые в этом classpath находятся. Надо добавить драйвер в classpath или classpath поправить, чтобы указывал на драйвер.

Comment: Ну или, если MYSQL драйвер у вас старый, то с ним нужно `Class.forName()` использовать, которого в вашем коде нет.